# Only single foreign key is being acknowledge

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I have two tables, namely, `manager` and `employee`. I have managed to successfully implement a foreign key constraint on `employee` table and and everything seems to be working fine. However, whenever I query the database to find out which manager is allocated to which employee using `INNER JOIN`, the result it gives me is limited to the number of manager `id`s I have. For example if 2 particular employees are allocated to the same manager, it only gives me one result in terms of the list of employee's who is allocated to the same manager.

I tried using `LEFT JOIN` to see whether the foreign I want to impelement are actually inserted. To my surprise it gives me the result of `NULL` for columns which explicitly have the same foreign key as those ones that is actually working. Sorry in advance if you find my description unclear as English is not my first language. However, to give you a better idea of what im trying to explain my tables are as follows

```
employee                                              Manager
emploee ID | firstname | lastname | managerid         managerid |fname | lastname
1              john        doe       1                   1       gordon   soo
2              ian         lee       1                   2       justin   freeman
3              faye        eva       2                   3       sai      chow
```

What happens when I try `LEFT JOIN`:

```
Employee name |lasttname | ManagerNAme

john           doe            gordon
ian            lee            NUll
```

I have tried `WHERE` clause as well a checked if both tables are on INODB and have the same collation but I just cant seem to fix it. Hope you can help.

Comment: Please show your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand the question, you need a simple `JOIN` on the tables. As you don't show your queries, it is hard to say what's wrong. This is probably what you want:

```
SELECT 
    e.firstname, e.lastname, m.fname
FROM
    Manager m    
    JOIN employee e ON e.managerid = m.managerid
```

Comment: SELECT employee.firstname, manager.firstname, employee.lastname
FROM employee
INNER JOIN manager ON employee.id = manager.id

Comment: what is employee.id and manager.id? You don't have these in your tables.

Comment: that is exactly what i did and im pretty sure that my systax is correct as it doesnt give me any error. My problem is the results i get are limited to the numbe of manager id i have. For example if two employee's have the same manager, the results only shows me one and the latter returns null even though i have specified that employee two is also allocated to the same manager

Comment: employee.id corresponds to my the employee table primary key whereas manager.id corresponds to the primary key in manager table

Comment: Well, then employee.id = manager.id is wrong, isn't it? It should be employee.managerid = manager.id

Comment: thank you very much sir.. I can finally die in peace took me all night to fix that..

Comment: Welcome ha-ha. One thing to learn from it: don't code at night :)